# Safely alter the plist on Calendar.app

Tags: calendar, dock, plist

I want to add `<key>LSUIElement</key> <true/>` to the plist of Calendar.app like I would other apps because I don't want it in the dock or my task bar. This being a super-special Apple app, I need special permission. Could anyone tell me how to safely do this?

Answer (score 1):

To safely alter the file just make a copy or backup of the file and then work with the original:

- To modify the file log-in as a sudoer (usually an admin account) and open Terminal.
- Enter the following to backup the file:

  ```
  sudo cp /Applications/Calendar/Contents/Info.plist /Applications/Calendar/Contents/Info.plist.backup
  ```

  you have to enter your password then.
- Open nano to modify the plist content:

  ```
  sudo nano /Applications/Calendar/Contents/Info.plist
  ```
- now add

  ```
  <key>LSUIElement</key>
  <true/>
  ```

  after the line containing `<dict>` (usually the 5th line).
- Hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> to write the changes to file. Then hit Hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> to quit nano.
- Open Calendar and check if it works. ***(It doesn't work, Calendar crashes immediately)***
- to revert the changes enter:

  ```
  sudo rm /Applications/Calendar/Contents/Info.plist
  sudo mv /Applications/Calendar/Contents/Info.plist.backup /Applications/Calendar/Contents/Info.plist
  ```

  to remove the modified file and rename the backup file.
- Enter exit and quit Terminal
- Change the icon of Calendar to a more pleasurable one.

Answer (score 0):

I would just make a copy of the original .plist on your desktop for example. Then copy it a second time, make your changes in this second copy and then drag and drop the edited .plist back to where it came from.

Try out Calendar and see if all is well, if not you can always drag the original copy on the desktop back to where it should be.